# How to access Firefox Sync bookmarks without Firefox

Tags: api, firefox, synchronization

Firefox 4 syncs bookmarks and other settings to a host run by mozilla.

- How do I access my bookmarks there (without Firefox)?
- Is there a documented API?

It seems https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firefox_Sync should contain the neccessary documentation but all links except the first point to empty pages.

I found a script called weave.py here https://github.com/mozilla/weaveclient-python/blob/master/weave.py that is supposed to be able to access those bookmarks but it is unable to use my credentials. It seems to expect usernames without "@" characters.

Is there any documentation out there on how to access Firefox sync data. Preferably with examples.

Right now I don't even know the entry point to this supposed web service.

When I go to https://services.mozilla.com/ I can change my password and presumably remove everything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at https://wiki.mozilla.org/Services/Sync, I think that's the documentation you want. More detail is at https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Weave/Sync/1.1/API.

Comment: Thanks for the first Url. I did not find that on my own. Regarding the second URL: Are you sure Firefox uses version 1.1 of the Weave Sync API? Where is that documented? The release notes don't mention a version. 

Anyway. Do you happen to also know the entry URL for that API?

Comment: Good point: I haven't actually used that version, but I'd assumed they'd switched to that. There is a 1.0 api at https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Weave/Sync/1.0/API: it would have to be one of those, unless they have yet another undocumented API they use.

Comment: When I create a sync account with Firefox 4 I have to use an email address. There is no way to enter a username without an "@" sign in it. Yet the server always gives me a Bad Request response if I use that email address in the URL. How is this supposed to work?

Comment: Not sure. I'm assuming url encoding or base64 or something.

Comment: I got an answer from Tarek Ziadé. He said its sha-base32-ed. I'll try that.

Answer (score 7):

Indeed, the username is sha1 + base32. Python code:

```
import base64
import hashlib
base64.b32encode(hashlib.sha1('myemail@gmail.com').digest()).lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

The WeaveID returned by `ID.get("WeaveID").username` is indeed SHA-1 hashed and base32 encoded.
A nice way to do this in Java is to use Apache Commons Codec, which includes Base32 since version 1.5:

```
public String getWeaveID(String email) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    byte[] sha = DigestUtils.sha(email.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    Base32 b32 = new Base32(64, new byte[]{ }, false);
    return b32.encodeToString(sha).toLowerCase();
}
```